# Expressing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i$ as an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

**Problem**

I have the following sum:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i$$

**My thoughts**

This is in the chapter about integrals, and I recognize that this looks similar to the type of limit/sum that can be expressed as a definite integral. I've even ventured an "educated guess" that this would equal $$\int_0^1\sqrt x\mathrm dx$$ but the problem I have is that this is, as stated, just a guess. I don't know how to *show* that this is correct.

More specifically, my problem lies with the $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ part. I can't see how I'm meant to work that in.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt {\frac i n}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The right Riemann sum (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for more details) is defined by
$$
\Delta x[f(a+\Delta x)+f(a+2\Delta x)+\ldots+f(b)].
$$
Set $\Delta x=n^{-1}$, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for each $x\ge0$, $a=0$ and $b=1$. Then the right Riemann sum becomes
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac i{n}}=\frac1{n^{3/2}}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{i}.
$$
Since the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is Riemann integrable, the Riemann sum converves to the integral and we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^{3/2}}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{i}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}
=\int_0^1\sqrt x\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: When you reach $\sqrt\frac in$, I don't see that the next step follows (though I trust it does). Does this have to do with that we have $\sqrt{i \Delta x}$ there?

Comment: @Alec I updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks! That made it a bit clearer, yes. The only thing I'm missing here is how you find the limits $a=0, \ b=1$. If I were doing this on an exam, I don't necessarily see how I would know to "set a=0, b=1".

Comment: @Alec If we recognise that this is the right Riemann sum with $\Delta x=n^{-1}$, then we can do the following. The first element of the right Riemann sum is $f(a+\Delta x)$ and the last element is $f(b)$. The first element of our sum is $\sqrt{n^{-1}}$ which means that $a=0$ and the last element of our sum is $\sqrt 1$ which means that $b=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ i/n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Hence $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i \to \int_0^1\sqrt x\mathrm dx$

Comment: When you reach $f(i/n)$, how does the $\mathrm dx$ come to be? I vaguely see that $\sqrt{i/n} = \sqrt{i\Delta x}$ but does that equal $\sqrt i \mathrm dx$ in the end? I know that $\mathrm dx$ represents an infinitesimal $\Delta x$ but since it's inside the radical, I don't see how to work it out.